# Deploying/Creating own virtual machine on demand setup

Tags: maven-plugin, virtual-machine

I have a need to deploy email server and subsequently create java plugins for it.

I got my hands on a second hand HP Proliant server.

I am planning to use it in following ways:

1. Deploy a setup on the Server that will create and provide Virtual machines on demand so that different versions of the build can be maintained for testing local code changes and experimentation. How to do it, what opensource packages best fit here?
2. Since I use maven project, what best plugin I need to use so that via maven commands only I can deploy my project on the virtual machine provided from #1 and run my test cases over it.
   (This is from Developer local build perspective), CI etc is setup separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For #1**

I am using Sun virtual box for running my virtual machines as rest of the solutions like Xen Cloud platform, OpenStack etc are still not out of box kind solution and require steep learning curve.

Vmware player provides limited functionality and doesn't provide cloning of VM's.

**For #2**

Unable to automate complex deployment via maven plugins, using custom shell scripts still.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting approach can be to go for the cloud to do that - there are various utilities and services which allows you to create infrastructure using code.

Depending on the VMs/applications you would like to provision, different services/utilities can be relevant (e.g. AWS's cloudformation, Openstack's heat, etc...).

An interesting solution is provided by [Ravello Systems](http://www.ravellosystems.com), which basically lets you easily create a full blown replica of an application in the cloud, and they even implemented a maven plugin to help in automating that. Take a look at http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/ravello_maven_plugin/